# Is hook_boot() deprecated?

Tags: hooks

I created a module in Drupal 7. Two years ago, that was working for me. Right now,  it is not working, as well as `drupal_add_js()`. It is also giving me an error when I implement `hook_boot()`.

Is `hook_boot()` deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated? I suppose yes, technically, it was. `hook_boot()` was completely removed in Drupal 8, so you could take that to mean that it was deprecated in 7, even though it doesn't look like it was formally documented in the usual way (for example by adding `@deprecated` to the doc block in the system.api.php file).

However it was never, and won't ever be, *removed* from Drupal 7. Plenty of core and contributed modules are still using it just like they always have done. If your code is suddenly not working, check what else has changed that might be affecting it; `hook_boot()` hasn't gone anywhere.

Comment: When I use.
function zoomnow_init(){
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'zoomnow') . '/zoomnow.css');
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'zoomnow') . '/jquery.zoom.js');
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'zoomnow') . '/zoomnow.js');

}
Its working for me..

Comment: When I use hook_boot its not initialing my css and js file.but after using hook_init its working form me. not getting.

Comment: Without knowing more about the code and how/where/what it's doing I can't really comment. I can only say that `hook_boot()` still exists, and is still invoked by Drupal during an early stage of its bootstrap. I have dozens of D7 sites running that use `hook_boot()` without issue

Comment: To add to that, deprecated functions would note that they are deprecated in their phpdoc comment.